# Differences between Code Contract and Spec#

Tags: c#, code-contracts, design-by-contract, spec#

I want to implement the DBC in C#. I faced with the Spec# and Code Contract for it.
What is the difference between Spec# and Code Contract?

Comment: I think that both Spec# and Code Contracts were competing ideas (or similar but different) around building contracts. I can't be sure, but I think Code Contracts won out that race.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the [Code Contracts FAQs at Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/faq.aspx):

> **Do Code Contracts have anything to do with Spec#?**
>
> Code Contracts is a spin-off from the Spec# project. Spec#’s research focus is to
> understand the meaning of object invariants in the presence of
> inheritance, call backs, aliasing and multi-threading. Spec# is a
> superset of C# v2.0 and uses a source level rewriter to weave the
> contracts into the code. It uses verification condition generation and
> a theorem prover for the static verification of Spec# code. But
> dealing soundly with all the complex issues around maintaining object
> invariants has a price: verification becomes non-trivial. That’s why
> Spec# also needs an ownership discipline to know which objects may
> alias or cannot alias each other.
>
> Code Contracts is the result of learning from Spec# what works and
> what doesn’t. Unlike Spec#, Code Contracts are language agnostic, and
> thus work across all .NET languages, from VB to C# to F#. The rewriter
> works on MSIL and thus had no dependency on particular compilers. Its
> static analysis engine uses abstract interpretation, which is much
> faster and more predictable than verification; furthermore abstract
> interpretation infers loop invariants and method contracts, which
> helps in adoption and ease of use of Code Contracts.

So, it seems that Code Contracts would be the more 'supported' tool going forward.

Comment: Important that "supported" remains in quotes here. Code Contracts is still considered an alpha-quality research project, it does not have the rigorous testing of a fully supported product and does occasionally break.